# Opencart Upload Image From Customer Page

Tags: php, image, opencart

I want to ask how to upload image from Opencart customer site (e.g profile picture) and resizing it? My code can upload image, but it can't resize my image. If I have file 5MB image file, I want to shrink the file to around 200KB. I already tried PHP function imagejpeg, but it doesn't work, it won't upload the image.Here's my code:

```
//Check the post
if((!empty($_FILES)) && ($_FILES['photo']['size'] > 0) && ($_FILES['photo']['error'] == 0)){
//check extension
   $fileType = strtolower(pathinfo(basename($this->request->files['photo']['name']), PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
   if($fileType != "jpeg" && $fileType != "jpg" && $fileType != "png" && $fileType != "bmp"){
      echo "<script>
       alert('Extension allowed : jpeg, jpg, png, dan bmp. Your extension: ".$fileType."');
       window.location.href='javascript: window.history.go(-1)';
     </script>";
      die();
   }
  //check image size
   if($this->request->files['photo']['size'] > 5000000){
      echo "<script>
       alert('File too big, max. 5000000 (5MB). Your file: ".$this->request->files['photo']['size']."');
       window.location.href='javascript: window.history.go(-1)';
     </script>";
      die();
   }
   $fileName = $this->request->files['photo']['name'];
   $newimg = date('YmdHis', time());
   $arr = explode(".", $fileName);
   $extension = strtolower(array_pop($arr));
   $foto = $newimg.".".$extension;
   $uploads_dir = 'image/data/profile/';
   if (is_uploaded_file($this->request->files['photo']['tmp_name'])) {
   //i want to shrink image size before this upload
      move_uploaded_file($this->request->files['photo']['tmp_name'], $uploads_dir.$foto);
   }
}
else{
   echo "<script>
       alert('Please choose a photo');
       window.location.href='javascript: window.history.go(-1)';
     </script>";
      die();
   $foto = '';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try following code snippet to reduce image size during image upload -

```
<?php
    function reduce_image_size($source_url, $destination_url, $quality) {

        $info = getimagesize($source_url);

        if ($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg')
            $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source_url); 
        else if ($info['mime'] == 'image/gif')
            $image = imagecreatefromgif($source_url); 
        else if ($info['mime'] == 'image/png')
            $image = imagecreatefrompng($source_url);

        imagejpeg($image, $destination_url, $quality);
        return $destination_url;
    }

    if($_POST) {
        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
            $output = $_FILES["file"]["error"];
        } else if (($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") ||
                ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") ||
                ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png") ||
                ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")) {

            $destination = 'reduced.jpg';
            $filename = reduce_image_size($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $destination, 80);
            $output = 'Done.';
        } else {
            $output = "Uploaded image should be jpg or gif or png.";
        }

        echo $output . " <a href=''>Reload</a>"; die;
    }
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Reduce Image Size with PHP</title>
    </head>
    <body>
<form action="" name="img_compress" id="img_compress" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
               Upload: <input type="file" name="file" id="file"/>
               <input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" class="submit btn-success"/>
   </form>
     </body>
</html>
```